# Is this how to handle two ajax request based on get value from url?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I would like to sort data based on city chosen. Data from home-page and product-page are different. So if i view home-page and select city, first ajax request will send and if i view product-page and select city, second ajax request will send.

So the below ajax code will send request based on if condition and the condition within the if statement is telling what page is viewing from GET variable in the browser URL. I don't know if it is right syntax for the below if statements or not? If not, what is the right way to achieve my goal?

Example URL: http://localhost/myproject/index.php?view=home-page

```
<script>
    function sortResult(str) {
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else { // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                if ($_GET["view"] == "home-page") {
                    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    xmlhttp.open("GET", "home-page-new.php?q=" + str, true);
                    xmlhttp.send();
                }
                if ($_GET["view"] == "product-page") {
                    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    xmlhttp.open("GET", "product-page-new.php?q=" + str, true);
                    xmlhttp.send();
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Here is HTML:

```
<select name="sortby" class="form-control" id="city"  onchange="sortResult(this.value)">
    <option value="">Choose CiTY</option>
    <option value="City 1">City 1</option>
    <option value="City 2">City 2</option>
    <option value="City 3">City 3</option>
</select>
```

Here is home-page html:

```
<div id="result">
  Old content will be replaced by new content here
</div>
```

Here is product-page html:

```
<div id="result">
  Old content will be replaced by new content here
</div>
```

Comment: Why is this question tagged with `jQuery` ?

Answer (score -1):

First of all you can not use $_GET["view"]   directly into javascript. 
Take one variable like below :

```
   <script >
    var view = <?php echo $_GET["view"]; ?>;
    ...........
if(view =="home-page")
 {
   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
   xmlhttp.open("GET","home-page-new.php?q="+str,true);
   xmlhttp.send();
 }
 if(view =="product-page")
 {
   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
   xmlhttp.open("GET","product-page-new.php?q="+str,true);
   xmlhttp.send();
 }
 ................
  </script>
```